# How to zip more than 8 different types of mono

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to make 9 api calls at the same time. All of these calls would return different response objects. Before this we have 8 api calls and since these mono were different types, I used Mono.zip like below.

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<Service1Response>> monoService1 = callService1();
Mono<ResponseEntity<Service2Response>> monoService2 = callService2();
...
Mono<ResponseEntity<Service3Response>> monoService7 = callService7();
Mono<ResponseEntity<Service4Response>> monoService8 = callService8();

MixResponse mix = Mono.zip(monoService1, monoService2, monoService3, monoService4, monoService5, monoService6, monoService7, monoService8).flatMap(response -> {
  MixResponse mixResp = new MixResponse();
  mixResp.setResponse1(response.getT1().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse2(response.getT2().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse3(response.getT3().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse4(response.getT4().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse5(response.getT5().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse6(response.getT6().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse7(response.getT7().getBody());
  mixResp.setResponse8(response.getT8().getBody());
  return Mono.just(mixResp);
})).block();
```

but now we have one more service and Mono.zip supports only up to 8 monos. Is there anyway aside from Mono.zip that I could use in my situation? Sorry if this question looks dumb. I'm new in spring-webflux. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Mono.zip` that is taking `Iterable` as an argument and combinator function to combine results and casting to the specific type:

`<R> Mono<R> zip(final Iterable<? extends Mono<?>> monos, Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> combinator)`

```
List<Mono<? extends ResponseEntity<?>>> requests = List.of(
        monoService1, 
        monoService2, 
        monoService3, 
        monoService4
);

Mono.zip(requests, responses -> {
    MixResponse mixResp = new MixResponse();
    mixResp.setResponse1(((ResponseEntity<Service1Response>) responses[0]).getBody());
    mixResp.setResponse2(((ResponseEntity<Service2Response>) responses[1]).getBody());
    mixResp.setResponse3(((ResponseEntity<Service3Response>) responses[2]).getBody());
    mixResp.setResponse4(((ResponseEntity<Service4Response>) responses[3]).getBody());
    return mixResp;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, that generic expression works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

My solution that works similarly to `TupleUtils.function`:

```
Mono.zip(
    monoService1,
    monoService2,
    monoService3,
    monoService4,
    monoService5,
    monoService6,
    monoService7,
    monoService8 
).zipWith(Mono.zip( // the max number of Mono.zip which can return a tuple is 8, therefore we had to split into two chunks
    monoService9,
    monoService10 
), BigTuple::new
).map(bigFunction((res1, res2, res3, res4, res4, res5, res6, res7, res8, res9, res10) ->
    // resX are all preserving their types and all named
));
```

For this to work you have to implement your `BigTuple` and `bigFunction`. This is all boilerplate code unfortunately.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;

public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, R> Function<BigTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>, R> bigFunction(
        BigFunction<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, R> function) {
    return tuple -> function.apply(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT3(), tuple.getT4(), tuple.getT5(), tuple.getT6(),
            tuple.getT7(), tuple.getT8(), tuple.getT9(), tuple.getT10());
}

@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class BigTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>  {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    T3 t3;
    T4 t4;
    T5 t5;
    T6 t6;
    T7 t7;
    T8 t8;
    T9 t9;
    T10 t10;

    BigTuple(Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8> objects1, Tuple2<T9, T10> objects2) {
        this(objects1.getT1(), objects1.getT2(), objects1.getT3(), objects1.getT4(), objects1.getT5(),
                objects1.getT6(), objects1.getT7(), objects1.getT8(), objects2.getT1(), objects2.getT2());
    }
}

private interface BigFunction<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, R> {
    R apply(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, T8 t8, T9 t9, T10 t10);
}
```